# Can't find my textbox inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, repeater, findcontrol

I am making a menu for a cafe. It shows the food and rinks items, the price and then I want a textbox, where people can write how much of each they want to buy, shown in a textbox. Then I want each textbox to have a unique ID based on the menu items ID.

This is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h2>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "typenavn") %></h2>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 400px">
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productName") %>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 400px">
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pris") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
protected void ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater ChildRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");

            HiddenField hide = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(hide.Value);

            var query = from es in gr.products
                        where es.typeID == id
                        select es;

            List<product> list = new List<product>();
            foreach (product pro in query)
            {
                list.Add(pro);
            }

            ChildRepeater.DataSource = list;
            ChildRepeater.DataBind();

            int h = 0;

            foreach (RepeaterItem item1 in ChildRepeater.Items)
            {
                if (item1.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item1.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)item1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
                    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)item1.FindControl("HiddenField2") as HiddenField;

                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                    {
                        txt.ID = "HB" + list[h].id.ToString();
                        hf.Value = list[h].id.ToString();
                        h++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anybody got any ideas about how to find the textbox??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484806/accessing-textboxes-in-repeater-control

use this link hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search for the TextBox in the [RepeaterItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx). So you either handle the inner Repeater's ItemDataBound event or you simply iterate all RepeaterItems:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in ChildRepeater.Items){
  if(item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
    var txt = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried: ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
                Repeater Parent = MainContent.FindControl("ParentRepeater") as Repeater;
                Repeater Child = Parent.FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater; But it only gives me the parent repeater, but not the chilrepeater

Comment: Yes, as i've already said. The NamingContainer of your Textbox is the child repeater's RepeaterItem. So it's not possible to use FindControl via the outer Repeater without using a recursive function. Btw, you should see my edited version that does not contain a `TablePanier` and shows you how to find the `Textbox1`

Comment: So what have you tried and where(edit your question)? Does your `ChildRepeater` has items? Did you debug it?

Comment: I think i got it to work now :) Thanks alot for all the help. I did a debug and found that i had forgot to change all the 'item' to 'item1'