# How to access controls inside repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have placed a TextBox inside repeater but I don't know what will be the ID to access those TextBoxes. So how I should access them ?

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

**No FindControl please !**

I want something similar to following code to access.

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hi";
```

Comment: How are you selecting a row?

Comment: I'm not selecting anything. In code-behind I use the ID of controls to check what is entered.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484806/accessing-textboxes-in-repeater-control

Comment: It's not duplicate but similar..however I'm looking for a solution other than using FindControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do it like so...

```
// another way to search for asp elements on page


 public static void GetAllControls<T>(this Control control, IList<T> list) where T : Control
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                if (c != null && c is T)
                    list.Add(c as T);
                if (c.HasControls())
                    GetAllControls<T>(c, list);
            }
        }
```

Comment: My app it's hard coded and I have no knowledge about ID's. That's why I don't want to use FindControl. As I mentioned your answer doesn't fit this question. However thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So you think your answer is ok? It practically the same

Comment: if you delete your first solution then I can accept your updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way, without a lot of recursion with FindControl (which isn't very efficient) is to wire up the OnItemDataBound even on the repeater, and in the code behind access the data row's individual elements. You pretty much have to use FindControl - but in this case you don't need to recurse into the controls collection.

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>";
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way, imho, is to iterate through all items of the repeater, find the desired control and do whatever you want with it. 
Example, in VB.NET

```
 For Each item As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
     Dim temporaryVariable As TextBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
     temporaryVariable.Text = "Hi!"
 Next
```

But remember, you have to this **after** Repeater1.*DataBind*()

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Repeater.ItemDataBound*

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```